# Angular 2 How to find 404 Not Found Page Referer URL?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my scenario , I need to know where user comes to 404 page what was the URL ?

How can I find referrer URL of 404 page on angular2 ? For tell the GoogleAnalytics.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason to include Google Analytics tag. You just need to configure your routes to redirect to 404. If the GA tag is placed good, it will automatically track the pageview. I am removing Google Analytics tag

Comment: It was all about GA. And you gave the answer about. It will automatically track the pageview.

Comment: no GA has nothing to do how to search for 404. It will trigger whatever the page url is.

Comment: I understood thank you.